# Get a String out of Try-Catch

Tags: java, string, scope

I have a little issue with try-catch.

My Target is to get the `test` and `test2` values out of the try block that I can use it later.

How to handle it?

```
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int test = Integer.parseInt("123");
            String test2 = "ABCD";
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have scope issues and move the declaration to out of try.

Comment: declare in another scope eg class

Comment: @terades: pls user camel-case for variable names. everything in uppercase is reserved for final variables / constants.

Comment: My suggestion is to move the declaration out of try as Suresh-Atta mentioned and assign the final values in your final block. Hope you know why we use try-catch blocks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you wrote:

> ....*that I can use it later*....

it depends what later means, if you mean later but in the same method then do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test2 = "";
    try {
        int test = Integer.parseInt("123");
        test2 = "ABCD";
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

then after that you can use a method like

```
test2.isEmpty()
```

to check if the content in the string was updated to **ABCD** or not...

if you mean later but in another static method then do.

```
public class MyApplication  {
    static String test2 = "";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int test = Integer.parseInt("123");
            test2 = "ABCD";
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ill try it out :)

Comment: hey! I saw your edit of the question. pls, remove "thanks" next time too. +1

Comment: mach ich :D // i'll

Answer (score 4):

Just declare them in the external scope :

```
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int test = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // setting to max value to check if it was set later
        String test2 = null;

        try {
            test = Integer.parseInt("123");
            test2 = "ABCD";
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! :)

Comment: I think i understand it now.. when i declare the TEST and TEST2 first the try function set the value of those to "xxx" and ends and then i can use the values later on or?:)

Comment: Initialize TEST to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so that you can check if it has been set or not. If it's initialized to 0 you cannot tell whether it's the default value or the value that was just set (not for this particular case where 123 != 0).

Comment: @terades Exaclty. And you can initialize it like StephaneM said

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you have scope issues meaning your variable Test and Test 2 are declared within the try-catch block. Because of these you cannot access this variable outside the try-catch block. There are couple of ways to overcome this, the easiest way out is to declare just after your main function declaration or your class declaration.

```
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int TEST = 0;
        String TEST2 = "";

        try {
            TEST = Integer.parseInt("123");
            TEST2 = "ABCD";
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Well explained !